# Why "Koran" changed to "Quran"?

Tags: etymology, history, transliteration

According to the article [Quran or Koran?](http://www.ajr.org/Article.asp?id=4239), in 2000, AP started to use *Quran* instead of the more familiar *Koran*.

Does anybody have information as to why this happened, and why newspapers today are using *Quran* instead of *Koran*?

Comment: You could ask Norm Goldstein, editor of the AP Stylebook.  [Style Weekly](http://www.styleweekly.com/richmond/fighting-words/Content?oid=1386155&mode=print) did just that, although somewhat frustratingly, the quote appears to be cut off toward the end.

Comment: This does not answer your question but I would like to mention that both transliterations 'Koran' and 'Quran' exist in English at least since 19th century. For example, F. Steingass uses both in his Arabic-English and Persian-English dictionaries.

Comment: Did you read the [article](http://www.ajr.org/Article.asp?id=4239)? It answers both your questions. 1): *The changes reflect a balancing act taking place not only at the AP but also in newsrooms around the country. In an e-mail interview, Stylebook Editor Norm Goldstein wrote: "We try to come up with a spelling that is understandable to United States readers and as close as possible to the actual pronunciation."* 2) And then five editors and a journalist answer why their newspaper uses what they do.

Comment: Somewhat similar question on English Language Learners: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/823/54

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It represents a more careful transliteration:

- There are two different Arabic letters 'ka' and 'qaf' which both correspond more or less to Latin (English) 'k'. They have different sounds, but the difference is not a significant one in English. So an unlearned transliterator might use 'k' for both, but that will lose a distinction in the Arabic, so it is now more usual to use a transcription which distinguishes these two letters, and their sounds, even though people who are unfamiliar with Arabic will probably not make a distinction between them.
- Standard literary Arabic does not have an 'o' vowel, though some varieties of Arabic do. So in the most general Arabic, the word has the 'u' vowel.

Thus in modern transliterations of Arabic, the word will appear as "quran" (or for an even more careful transliteration, "qur'an").

There has been an increasing tendency to replace traditional English versions of foreign words, especially names, by more scholarly or official versions in the last few decades (consider "Beijing" and "Mumbai" as opposed to "Peking" and "Bombay"), though in the end I think this is a political rather than a literary trend.

Comment: +1 And a yet more careful transliteration will employ < ’ > instead of < ' > in order to distinguish the sound represented by IPA [ʔ] from that transliterated < ‘ > and represented by IPA [ʕ].

Answer (score 3):

The 'K' is the equivalent of Arabic "Kaf" in English and French (mybe other languages), to highlight the difference between 'Kaf' and 'Qaf', using 'Q' instead of 'K' is more appropriate.

Comment: Hebrew transliteration as well distinguishes between K and Q.

Comment: @AdamMosheh: I had the impression that Hebrew transliteration is highly non-standardized and variable between different transcribers (and even different words). Take “קבלה”. We see the initial consonant transcribed as K, Q, or even C; the second transcibed as B or BB, and it may end with -AH or a simple A. The forms with "k,"like "Kabbalah" or "Kabbala," seem to me to be more common than those with Q.

Comment: @sumelic – K and Q actually are intended to make different consonantal sounds in Hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Organizations that want to look sophisticated and non-nationalistic and sensitive may use a more "accurate" and "scholarly" spelling such as "quran"

In the column "Don't Mention the Jihad" (warning: the column may be offensive), right-wing commentator Mark Steyn, who is against being sophisticated, non-nationalistic, and sensitive, mocks such changes, [saying](http://www.steynonline.com/4684/dont-mention-the-jihad)

> Do you find our language too insensitive? Fine. Let's make "Koran"
>   "Quran", or better yet, "Qu'ran", or, if you prefer, "Qu'~*ran",
>   whatever you want, the more the merrier, toss a couple of [wingdings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings) in
>   there. In the Thirties, when Churchill was attacking the Munich
>   Agreement, the sensitivity-check didn't automatically amend it to
>   "München". ... Hitherto, Anglicisation of foreign place names has been an accepted custom ...

Comment: Why didn't he change his name to Stine?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus because some people (e.g Mark Steyn) like to talk a lot and do nothing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind the fact that it's not pronounced ko-ran, or kor-an.  It's said just like we spell it. If you need pronunciation spelling, it would be closest to kur-on. It's the name of a holy book.  Use the accurate title and learn the correct way to pronounce it.  It's not difficult.

Comment: Hello, Deanna, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. The person who posted this question wasn't complaining about the change in spelling or doubting its validity; he or she was simply asking why it happened—and unfortunately, your answer is rather sketchy on that point. As I recall, a similar change occurred in the spelling of the last name of the former leader of Libya, which at various times was given as (among other things) _Ghaddafi,_ _Gaddafi_, _Kadhafi_, and _Qadhafi_.  Is the spelling change to _Quran_ part of a larger shift in Arabic-to-English transliteration?

Answer (score -5):

I think many people who do this are motivated by the fact that "Quran" doesn't look at all like a native English word. By implication, therefore, it might be an original "native Arab" form.

Obviously it *isn't*, since any relevant "native Arabs" didn't even use our alphabet, let alone our written conventions regarding the letter ***q***. But most dictionaries will have several words starting with the letter ***q*** where it's *not* followed by ***u***, and they're invariably to do with "things Arabic".

The form we're looking at here looks like an effort to allude to that "**u**-less **q**". I don't speak Arabic, so I don't know if the lack of a "pronounceable" vowel after ***qu*** may also reflect the fact that native speakers of the relevant languages don't normally enunciate much of a vowel before ***-ran***.

But I doubt that's really a significant factor. Mostly it's just a somewhat clumsy attempt to show respect for what *might* have been a traditional native spelling (but in fact it's not).

---

EDIT: In case it's not obvious, I'm aware that 'Kaf' and 'Qaf' are distinct phonemes in Arabic. By long-standing convention, we use that latter representation, even though it "breaks the rules" for English, because there's no reasonable alternative in that particular circumstance.

I wouldn't object to *Quoran* (which has been used, though not so often). But I don't see why we should welcome a [relatively new trend](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Koran,Quran,Quoran&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) that runs counter to an otherwise strictly-observed aspect of English orthography, simply to represent a phonemic difference that doesn't actually exist for us...

[image]

Comment: It's not "an effort to allude to that 'u-less q'. It is a precise rendering of a distinction which English fails to have.

Comment: @Colin: If you say so. I fail to see how breaking the rules of English orthography can be justified as making *a precise rendering of a distinction which English fails to have*. By that logic we should write the word "Koran" using Arabic scripts. Personally, I don't accept *café*, for example, as an "English" word at all, and no matter how many downvotes this answer collects, I remain highly sceptical about the "validity" of *Quran*.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it's factually incorrect to say this is done by relatively few people. As this chart from Google Ngram Viewer shows, the spelling *Quran* caught up to *Koran* in print twenty years ago: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HNGrj.png

Comment: @MετάEd: I don't know how you produced that graph, but it doesn't seem to accord with [this one looking at the last quarter-century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=koran%2Cquran&year_start=1980&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), or [this one looking over the longer term](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=koran%2Cquran&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). GB totals are *Koran*:4.4M, *Quran*:1.5M - I would say one in four is "relatively few" in this context.

Comment: I tend to agree, at least in part, with @FumbleFingers.  "Quran" would lead me to want to pronounce that "u" in the same way "u" is pronounced in such English words like "quit" or "quiet" -- i.e. a little "uh" in there somewhere.  Is this how the Arabic sounds when it pronounces "Quran"? +1 because I think this is a valid quibble.

Comment: One of most important features of the NGram generator is that it is  "case-sensitive". It is fallacious to offer {apples, oranges} in rebuttal of {Apples, Oranges} particularly when discussing the use of proper nouns.

Comment: @Fortiter: That's a fair point about the case. But it doesn't detract from *my* point that whereas *Koran* could be considered a "proper" English word, *Quran* can't, because it violates our standard orthographic conventions. It's used, but it's not really "English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The search URL corresponding to that chart is http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Koran%2CQuran&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share= -- and yes it is important to use title case in your search. Also I would avoid the smoothing feature. It can create misleading artifacts. Also the data before 1800 throws everything off pretty badly. In general, not just on this search.

Comment: @MετάEd: GB doesn't make very clear exactly what their "English" corpus contains, but if I switch to either "American" or "British" on your link, *Quran* is clearly not the spelling of choice. Therefore my guess is that non-Anglophones play a significant part in promoting what I continue to think of as a "non-standard" spelling that owes more to cultural sensitivities than any supposed "phonetic/historical accuracy".

Comment: @FumbleFingers What I'm seeing, looking at the various subsets, is exactly what I said before: overall parity 20 years ago. But I think I am also seeing a trend downward on Quran since then. That's a very short timespan for measuring trends, it's hard to know. And you've got me very curious about the subsets.

Comment: @MετάEd: Strange. When I switch your link to the ["American English" corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Koran%2CQuran&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=0&share=) that's not what I see. I'm seeing a steady increase in *Quran* over the past 50-60 years, but even looking at just the past 2-3 decades, it's pretty consistently 2:1 in favour of *Koran*.

Comment: Fumble, do you refer to the War in Irak? To standardize the orthography?

Comment: @Andrew: Lots of perfectly ordinary English words end in **k** (or **[vowel] + k**, if we want to be even more specific). But "normal" English words that start with **q** are all followed by **u** *then another vowel*. The form *Quran* is thus in (probably unique) violation of an otherwise rigid rule of English orthography. I've no problem with millions of Muslims living in Britain, but I don't see why that justifies promoting such an aberrant spelling. Especially when the general trend (admittedly, agonisingly slow) moves towards *standardising* our written forms, and we already have *Koran*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Numbers for 2008:
$ egrep 'Koran\s+2008' g*
googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-k:Koran      2008    48441   11363
googlebooks-eng-gb-all-1gram-20120701-k:Koran   2008    10459   1963
googlebooks-eng-us-all-1gram-20120701-k:Koran   2008    38514   9247
$ egrep 'Quran\s+2008' g*
googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-q:Quran      2008    30247   2584
googlebooks-eng-gb-all-1gram-20120701-q:Quran   2008    7939    496
googlebooks-eng-us-all-1gram-20120701-q:Quran   2008    17512   1575

Comment: @FumbleFingers You would think you could subtract "en" and "us" from "all" to get "other". But reading the papers, "all" is filtered with an OCR quality threshold of 80%, while "gb" and "us" filters use 60%. So it is not possible to say that gb + us + "other" = all. And sure enough Koran us 38514 + gb 10459 = 48973 > all 48441. Conclusion: hard to say.

Comment: @MετάEd: Well I doubt all those downvotes are because people take issue with the accuracy of *(relatively few)* in my answer, since that's hardly a substantive point anyway. Imho, the downvotes reflect the fact that many people think it's right and proper to override established standards for written English as a mark of "intercultural respect". Either that, or they think it's important that we write the word *Koran* in a way that reflects Arabic pronunciation, even though it involves a phoneme that Anglophones themselves don't naturally generate.

Comment: If it's not a substantive point then you might take it out of the first few words of your topic sentence. ;-)

Comment: @MετάEd: Done (but I added a chart to show the same info in a different form! :) It'll be interesting to see if future votes continue to split 2:1 *against* my point, now that it's potentially less "inflammatory".

Comment: Fumble, I think you will find Qureishi becoming a more common surname, and Quneitra is where the Dead Sea Scrolls were found. So Quran won't be the only proper noun with an attempt to distinguish letters in even casual transliteration. And I bet half the Quoran were typos for quorum!

Comment: @Andrew: I believe less than 1% of Americans are Muslims, but in the UK it's probably about 5% by now. If those people are to be regarded as "British", it seems only reasonable that they should speak and write "English", using typical Anglicised forms for referents which we *all* need to identify. I don't know the ancient Hebrew written form for "Bible" - but I bet that's not it, and I see no reason why "Koran" should be treated any different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can relate to your opinion that the popularity of "Quran", despite the existing well-established "Koran", may reflect a tendency to make words better resemble their donor languages, and your facts are well-supported, but I downvoted because of the excessive editorialisation. I sense an opinion, stated as fact, that presumes that loanwords are better spelled using as many English rules as possible, rather than foreign language rules. Even if this opinion was widely shared, it's presented in a less-than-respectful tone. I believe these traits do not belong in good answers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I am suggesting that _Koran_ is the odd-man-out on Arabic proper nouns, probably because it came into frequent use earlier. Iraq, Qureishi (also Qureshi), Quneitra. Times change. When Federico Peña was elected mayor of Denver, Colorado in the late 1980s, the New York Times spelled his name with a plain _n_. Last year, Enrique Peña Nieto was elected President of Mexico. By now, the Times has figured out how to get a diacritical mark; they spell his name with _ñ_.

Comment: Guys, please take this into chat--it'll be easier to have this type of extended discussion there.